# UML: What does an arrowhead inside a circle mean?

Tags: uml

What does an arrowhead inside a circle mean in the UML?

[image]

Comment: Honestly doesn't look normal. Perhaps it describes `realization` and `association` simultaneously?

Comment: Are you sure you have only one relation drawn rather than two superimposed ?

Comment: It does mean that the author has no idea of UML.

Comment: When you zoom and look you find that it's more like a circle with short horizontal line. This might be a minus or (since the associations would be at the same place) a plus symbol. Still something non-UMLish. Lots of room for speculations...

Answer (score 2):

It is an **invalid** UML symbol and nothing offical.

Comment: Well, but that is the actual answer.

Comment: @Ister the OP ask for "what it is", not "what it is not", else I can also put an answer saying it is not the representation of a cat, nor a car, nor a house ... ^^

Comment: The question is tagged UML, and the OP ask what this symbol means **in UML**. This answer correctly states that is doesn't mean anything in UML as it is in fact not UML.

Comment: The answer should probably be "It is an invalid UML symbol" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically I think that my comment above says it all. However, there are exceptions. For example in Enterprise Architect you can stereotype connectors and have any rendering you want, except for the two elements to be connected with a line. So you can create any kind of art along the connector. But then again, if you stereotype something it is valid only in a certain domain and needs extra documentation. If so in your case the author is to blame in any case for not providing that information.